# Group rows with common id in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, data-wrangling

I try to analyze the number of combinations with the same label but in different periods.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import last
from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_zip
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import *
```

```
data  = [["1", "2022-06-01 00:00:04.437000+02:00", "c", "A", "8", "6"],
        ["2", "2022-06-01 00:00:04.625000+02:00", "e", "A", "4", "2"],
        ["3", "2022-06-01 00:00:04.640000+02:00", "b", "A", "5", "3"],
        ["4", "2022-06-01 00:00:04.640000+02:00", "a", "A", "1", "6"],
       ["1", "2022-06-01 00:00:04.669000+02:00", "c", "B", "2", "4"],
        ["5", "2022-06-01 00:00:05.223000+02:00", "b", "B", "6", "8"],
        
       ["6", "2022-06-01 00:00:05.599886+02:00", "c", "A", None, "9"],
       ["1", "2022-06-01 00:00:05.740886+02:00", "b", "A", "8", "6"],
        ["2", "2022-06-01 00:00:05.937000+02:00", "a", "A", "4", "2"],
        ["3", "2022-06-01 00:00:05.937000+02:00", "e", "A", "5", "3"],
        ["4", "2022-06-01 00:00:30.746501-05:00", "b", "C", "1", "6"],
        ["1", "2022-06-01 00:00:30.747498-05:00", "d", "C", "2", "4"],
        
        ["5", "2022-06-01 00:00:30.789820+02:00", "b", "D", "6", "8"],
       ["6", "2022-06-01 00:00:31.062000+02:00", "e", "E", None, "9"],
       ["1", "2022-06-01 00:00:31.078000+02:00", "b", "E", "8", "6"],
        ["2", "2022-06-01 00:00:31.078000+02:00", "a", "F", "4", "2"],
       ["3", "2022-06-01 00:00:31.861017+02:00", "c", "G", "5", "3"],
        ["4", "2022-06-01 00:00:32.205639+00:00", "b", "H", "1", "6"],
        
        ["1", "2022-06-01 00:00:34.656000+02:00", "b", "I", "2", "4"],
        ["5", "2022-06-01 00:00:34.656000+02:00", "a", "I", "6", "8"],
       ["6", "2022-06-01 00:00:34.656000+02:00", "e", "I", None, "9"]]

columns = ['ID', 'source_timestamp', 'node_id', 'cd_equipment_no', 'x', 'y']


dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
dataframe = dataframe.withColumn("source_timestamp", to_timestamp(col("source_timestamp")))
```

This is how the data looks like

```
+---+--------------------+-------+---------------+----+---+
| ID|    source_timestamp|node_id|cd_equipment_no|   x|  y|
+---+--------------------+-------+---------------+----+---+
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              A|   8|  6|
|  2|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      e|              A|   4|  2|
|  3|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              A|   5|  3|
|  4|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              A|   1|  6|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              B|   2|  4|
|  5|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              B|   6|  8|
|  6|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              A|null|  9|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              A|   8|  6|
|  2|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              A|   4|  2|
|  3|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      e|              A|   5|  3|
|  4|2022-06-01 05:00:...|      b|              C|   1|  6|
|  1|2022-06-01 05:00:...|      d|              C|   2|  4|
|  5|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              D|   6|  8|
|  6|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      e|              E|null|  9|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              E|   8|  6|
|  2|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              F|   4|  2|
|  3|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              G|   5|  3|
|  4|2022-06-01 00:00:...|      b|              H|   1|  6|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              I|   2|  4|
|  5|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              I|   6|  8|
+---+--------------------+-------+---------------+----+---+
```

My intention is to create an identifier when the time is sorted ascending based on `source_timestamp`

This is what I get

```
window = Window.partitionBy('cd_equipment_no').orderBy(col('source_timestamp'))

dataframe = dataframe.select('*', row_number().over(window).alias('posicion'))
+---+--------------------+-------+---------------+----+---+--------+--------+
| ID|    source_timestamp|node_id|cd_equipment_no|   x|  y|posicion|posicion|
+---+--------------------+-------+---------------+----+---+--------+--------+
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              A|   8|  6|       1|       1|
|  2|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      e|              A|   4|  2|       2|       2|
|  3|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              A|   5|  3|       3|       3|
|  4|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              A|   1|  6|       4|       4|
|  6|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              A|null|  9|       7|       5|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              A|   8|  6|       8|       6|
|  2|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              A|   4|  2|       9|       7|
|  3|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      e|              A|   5|  3|      10|       8|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              B|   2|  4|       5|       1|
|  5|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              B|   6|  8|       6|       2|
|  4|2022-06-01 05:00:...|      b|              C|   1|  6|      20|       1|
|  1|2022-06-01 05:00:...|      d|              C|   2|  4|      21|       2|
|  5|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              D|   6|  8|      11|       1|
|  6|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      e|              E|null|  9|      12|       1|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              E|   8|  6|      13|       2|
|  2|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              F|   4|  2|      14|       1|
|  3|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              G|   5|  3|      15|       1|
|  4|2022-06-01 00:00:...|      b|              H|   1|  6|      19|       1|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              I|   2|  4|      16|       1|
|  5|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              I|   6|  8|      17|       2|
+---+--------------------+-------+---------------+----+---+--------+--------+
```

And this is what I want

```
+---+--------------------+-------+---------------+----+---+--------+--------+
| ID|    source_timestamp|node_id|cd_equipment_no|   x|  y|posicion|posicion|
+---+--------------------+-------+---------------+----+---+--------+--------+
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              A|   8|  6|       1|       1|
|  2|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      e|              A|   4|  2|       2|       2|
|  3|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              A|   5|  3|       3|       3|
|  4|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              A|   1|  6|       4|       4|
|  6|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              A|null|  9|       7|       1|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              A|   8|  6|       8|       2|
|  2|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              A|   4|  2|       9|       3|
|  3|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      e|              A|   5|  3|      10|       4|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              B|   2|  4|       5|       1|
|  5|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              B|   6|  8|       6|       2|
|  4|2022-06-01 05:00:...|      b|              C|   1|  6|      20|       1|
|  1|2022-06-01 05:00:...|      d|              C|   2|  4|      21|       2|
|  5|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              D|   6|  8|      11|       1|
|  6|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      e|              E|null|  9|      12|       1|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              E|   8|  6|      13|       2|
|  2|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              F|   4|  2|      14|       1|
|  3|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      c|              G|   5|  3|      15|       1|
|  4|2022-06-01 00:00:...|      b|              H|   1|  6|      19|       1|
|  1|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      b|              I|   2|  4|      16|       1|
|  5|2022-05-31 22:00:...|      a|              I|   6|  8|      17|       2|
+---+--------------------+-------+---------------+----+---+--------+--------+
```

Comment: What problem do you face exactly?

Comment: I want to have the different combinations based on `cd_equipment_no`. The problem is that the rows from the column `cd_equipment_no` have the same label. When I want to group the different combinations,then I get the total combinations from `A`. This is not what I want but I  would like to see the different combinations separately which appear in different time.

Comment: Could you provide an overview of what you get and what you actually want? It is really hard to follow your requirements currently.

Comment: Hello @RobertKossendey I already edited my question. I hope it is a little bit better

Comment: If you solve this on paper, what attribute in your data is used for grouping to create the combinations you want?